# Learning about Muktzeh

Tags: halacha, shabbat, muktzeh

I am looking for online sources that explain the general laws of Muktzeh in a simple and easy manner.

This doesn’t need to be in-depth, as that wouldn’t be simplified, but just an article, video, or presentation that outlines the categories of permitted and not permitted items.

Note, this is not meant for a child, rather explain the laws to an adult who isn’t so aware of what items are and are not muktzeh. So, the video needs not to be simplified for a child, but just give a general idea of what Muktzeh is.

Comment: Try this chart for simple clarification https://www.torahdesigns.com/muktzah-chart/

Answer (score 2):

The following are very helpful explanations, from more synthetized to more detailed

- [Halacha Yomit](http://halachayomit.co.il/en/Default.aspx?HalachaID=1866)
- R Doniel Neustadt at [torah.org](https://torah.org/torah-portion/weekly-halacha-5759-vayetze/)
- R Eliezer Melamed in [Peninei Halacha](https://ph.yhb.org.il/en/category/01/01-23/), if you ignore the sources this is the more pedagogical treatment of the topic. You can start with chapters 1 & 2 for a very good ovewview

The problem of the laws of *muktzeh* is that they are quite detailed and complex, and there is only so much you can do to simplify them.

Answer (score 1):

[Chabad.org](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/253229/jewish/Muktzeh.htm) explains the concept.

> Muktzeh (lit., “set aside”) refers to items that may not be moved or
> handled on Shabbat, the Jewish day of rest. One of the most famous
> Shabbat-related rabbinical injunctions, muktzeh was instituted to
> preserve the state of restfulness of this sacred day.
>
> The laws of muktzeh are codified in the Code of Jewish Law in the Laws
> of Shabbat.

It gives a summary of the History, Reasons, and Basic Principles.

You can also see in [halachipedia](https://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Muktzeh)

Answer (score 1):

Rabbi Doniel Braude has written a very well received book on Hilchos Shabbos called Learn Hilchos Shabbos in Just 3 Minutes a day.
This book is based on his daily 1 Minute Halacha email. One can sign up at https://www.torahcoach.net/#mailing-list and check the archives where he has done an excellent job of simplifying Hilchos Shabbos.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a big fan of Rav Shraga Kallus, a [Rosh Kollel](https://www.thesecondsederkollel.com/) and Rebbi in [Yeshivas Torah Ohr](http://www.torahore.org/staff) in Eretz Yisroel. He has a fantastic [website](https://ravkallus.com/) with all of his shiurim, including a whole series on Muktzeh [here](https://ravkallus.com/hilchos-muktza/)